# Cocoapods importing an external framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I built a Cocoapod which Crashlytics framework. 
I couldn't understand how to add the external framework (Crashlytics.framework) to the pod, so it will be imported on my project.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think this is something that should be directed directly to crashlytics' support:http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase

While at it, tell them to stop forcing their app installation on every dev computer :)

Comment: Agreed on that @eladleb, but I used Crashlytics as an example - it could be any other framework.

Answer (score 3):

If you can add the framework library to your Pod's source files, here's another way to do it.
For Pod, 'MyPod', add the framework to a directory 'MyPodSubDirectory'.
Then edit the podspec file as follows.

```
s.preserve_paths = 'MyPodSubDirectory/Crashlytics.framework'
s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework Crashlytics' }
s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyPodSubDirectory/Crashlytics.framework'
```

Comment: you don't have to add linker flags if you have already added it as a vendored framework:)

Comment: This makes sense. But now how would I #import Crashlytics? Should `#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>` still work? In my case, the framework is OpenCV, and `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` does not work.

Comment: shmin, did you find a solution to #import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>?

Answer (score 2):

[You want to use the `vendored_frameworks` property.](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#vendored_frameworks)

Comment: that link doesn't refer to vendored_frameworks page. Please update it